# How can i start a scheduled script with a button?

Tags: button, netsuite, suitescript

i want to create a button in a form that executes a scheduled script but nothing that i try works

I have tried the method addButton to call a function that create a task for the scheluded script but it only execute on form load

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/task", "N/ui/serverWidget"], function(task, serverWidget) {
  function beforeLoad(context) {

    context.form.addButton({
      id: "custpage_setTask",
      label: "Execute scheduled",
      functionName: executeScheduled()
    });
  }

  return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad
  };

  function executeScheduled() {
    var scriptTask = task.create({ 
      taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
      scriptId: 'customscript_sdr_ss_product_shortage',
      deploymentId: 'customdeployprodshortsearch'
     });

    var scriptTaskId = scriptTask.submit();

    log.debug('scriptTaskId', scriptTaskId);
  }
});
```

that execute the scheduled script but only in the form loading and then the button does not do anything, please help and thanks for reading

Comment: You need to run the executeScheduled() function in a separate client script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to do it at the end. It was creating 3 scripts, a user event that calls a client script, that do a get request to a suitelet with the function that creates the task for the scheduled script

This is the User event:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/task", "N/ui/serverWidget"], function(task, serverWidget) {
  function beforeLoad(context) {

    // internal id of the client script on file cabinet
    context.form.clientScriptFileId = 2343;
    context.form.addButton({
      id: "custpage_setTask",
      label: "Execute scheduled",
      functionName: 'redirect'
    });
  }

  return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
  };


});
```

This is the client script:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(["N/url", "N/https"], function(url, https) {
  function pageInit(context) {}

  function redirect() {
    var output = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: "customscript_sss_sl_startschedulescript",
      deploymentId: "customdeploy_sss_sl_startschedulescript"
    });

    log.debug('url', output);

    var response = https.get({
      url: output
    });

    log.debug('response', response);
  }

  return {
    pageInit: pageInit,
    redirect: redirect
  };
});
```

and this is the suitelet:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(["N/task"], function(task) {
  function onRequest(context) {
    executeScheduled();
  }

  function executeScheduled() {
    var scriptTask = task.create({
      taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
      scriptId: "customscript_sdr_ss_product_shortage",
      deploymentId: "customdeployprodshortsearch"
    });

    var scriptTaskId = scriptTask.submit();

    log.debug("scriptTaskId", scriptTaskId);
  }

  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  };
});
```

I hope this helps another one with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to export the button function.

```
      return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
        executeScheduled:executeScheduled        
      };
```

You also need to change your button options

```
context.form.addButton({
  id: "custpage_setTask",
  label: "Execute scheduled",
  functionName: executeScheduled
});
```

Comment: It gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error in the console when i click the button