# How can I dynamically call a scheduled script to run monthly in NetSuite without hardcoding parameters?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I create the scheduled script but I want to call scheduled script monthly & I want to call this script dynamically without hardcoded value in parameters of script deployment but issue we can't use variable task.create('N/Task' module ) in suitelet to call scheduled script using 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to do that indirectly. e.g. create a custom record and create and save a new instance of the custom record from your suitelet. The custom record has a longtext in which you save your parameters as JSON.

You create an after submit user event script on the custom record and have that trigger the task using the saved parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution here: [How can i start a scheduled script with a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150656/how-can-i-start-a-scheduled-script-with-a-button)

It would be helpful next time if you post any error or sample code you have.

It should be possible to run Scheduled Script through Suitelet. For example, we have a Suitelet Form that is linked to Transactions Tab, it loads a simple form with a title and Submit Button. The Submit button triggers the Scheduled Script and creates Invoices based on the returned Saved Search result. Something like this could work for you if you want to manually call the Scheduled Script every month.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a suitelet and add a button which will create a schedule script
   Task
2. Make a Suitelet or a Restlet that you call using an external ( there are plenty online) and triggers your schedule script .